# sql whith OR on associative table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have a products table (that are actual books) that i need to create a complicated search

I have a single textbox for search
So when i write a keyword in that textbox i need to return the products that

```
the title LIKE the keyword  (products table has a field title)
the ISBN  LIKE the keyword  (products table has a field isbn)
the products that keyword  LIKE author name   (this is a associative table product_authors)
the products that keyword  LIKE company name  (this is a associative table product_companies)
```

In the sql i have to create 4 OR sections for each one of the above
and i have trouble to write the sql for the associative table

The thing is that i can not use INNER JOIN because this means that the associative table must have a record
but in my case its not neccessary.
In my case this has to be OR

```
ex
SELECT * 
FROM products as p 
WHERE 
    (
        title LIKE '%keyword%'
        OR 
        isbn LIKE '%keyword%'
        OR 
            (how can i use OR when data are on associative table product_authors)
        OR 
            (how can i use OR when data are on associative table product_companies)    
    )
```

What i think is that i have to use a sub-select but i am not sure and i am little bit confused about it.

```
    SELECT * 
        FROM products as p 
        WHERE 
            (
                title LIKE '%keyword%'
                OR 
                isbn LIKE '%keyword%'
                OR 
                 product_id IN   (SELECT product_id 
    FROM product_authors WHERE author_id IN (1,2,3,4) )
                OR 
                    product_id IN   (SELECT product_id 
    FROM product_companies WHERE compamy_id IN (5,6,7,8) )
            )

where (1,2,3,4) are the ids that LIKE author_name 
and (5,6,7,8) are the ids that LIKE company_name
```

Can anyone help me write the sql command

Comment: Do a separate query with a `JOIN` and then use `UNION` to combine the two queries.

Comment: if `inner join` is not good, why not then use `left join` ?

Comment: Don't use INNER join if having an author is not mandatory... You can simply use left join!

Answer (score 1):

If inner join is no good for you, why not just go with left join?
You might want to group by product, as left joining the companies or authors table might given you a one-to-many relationship

```
select
    *
from
    products p
    left join product_authors on product_id
    left join authors on author_id
    left join product_companies on product_id
    left join companies on company_id
where
    title like '%keyword%'
    or isbn like '%keyword%'
    or author_name like '%keyword%'
    or company_name like '%keyword%'
group by -- add this group by if multiple authors or companies can be linked to the same product
    company_id
```

Comment: I tried the LEFT JOIN but is not returning the correct results

Comment: What is the incorrect result, and what is the correct result? Please elaborate. Also did you fill in the correct conditions in the `ON` statements?